# Saving multiple "self's" in a class python 3

Tags: python, oop, python-3.x

I am currently importing a file where each line contains specific information about a student.  The student's name is first followed by their grades.  Right now, I can print each name followed by a list of of their grades and their average.  What I'm trying to figure out is how to maintain each students grades and names, and be able to call them again into a different function in the same class.  As of right now, they are saving the last student as the "self".  The number of students is variable.

Comment: You might get a more helpful answer if you paste some code.

Answer (score 0):

If you save the last student as `self` you are doing something very fundamentally wrong. In fact, if you ever save anything as `self` you are doing it wrong.

`self` is the name (by convention, you can call it anything really) use in Python to refer to the object that the method belongs to. You never save anything into self.

What you need to do is to create a list of student objects.

Something like this:

```
class Student(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

students = [Student(name) for name in list_of_student_names]
```